# Does a cache buster on an image URL in CSS cause an extra request?

Tags: css, caching, optimization, browser-cache

If I add a cache buster to an image URL in one rule in my CSS

```
background: url(../img/sprite.png?version=20130205) no-repeat -75px -208px;
```

but the same CSS has other versions of the URL without the cache buster

```
background: url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;
```

does that cause another request for sprite.png?

Also if the browser parses the non-cache-busted URL first I'd assume it shows the cached image, if it has one, but will then request a new version of the image when it comes to the cache busted version - have I got it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will cause a new request for the image. If it is `?` the image will reload.

If you don't want to make new request use `#` in example

```
background: url(../img/sprite.png#version=20130205) no-repeat -75px -208px;
```

Comment: Thanks Enve, I've just checked with an http monitor and it does indeed create a second request. I guess if a hash string doesn't cause a second request it would also not work as  a cache buster, but thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you got it right. All points. When the portion following the `?` differs, it always reloads.

Comment: Not exactly true. Squid based proxy servers tend to ignore differences in query string part of the URI so its highly advised to use different names - i.e. `sprite-20130205.png` instead of `sprite.png?2013025` etc.

Comment: True. However the request will be carried out anyway, so from browser's perspective, it will always reload regardless of any proxy.